# É possível pegar API do Foursquare para ver localização de todos estabelecimentos?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, web-service, google-maps, app

É possível conseguir API do Foursquare, Google Maps ou outro site para adquirir a localização de todos os estabelecimentos de uma cidade?

Gostaria de saber ainda, se é possível filtrar por um ramo específico, como hotéis, escolas, etc.

Obrigado.

Comment: Márcio, *"É possível?"* é uma pergunta que tem duas respostas: 1) Sim, é possível. 2) Não, não é possível. . . Se quiser avançar mais rapidamente, pergunte: ***"Tentei tal método de tal API mas dá tal erro, como corrigir?"***.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. Utilizando Google Maps e API do Google Places você consegue listar todos os estabelecimentos que estejam cadastrados no mesmo, dividindo-os por ramo de atuação, pela distância que se encontra do usuário (utilizando o gps) entre várias outras coisas. Segue o link da documentação:

[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-ZA)